# aggregate in R with condition

Tags: r, aggregate-functions

Is there a way to do this with aggregate in R?

```
df.1 <- c("A","A","A","B","B","B")
df.2 <- c(100, 300, NA, 200, 100, 200)
df.3 <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3)

df <- data.frame(df.1, df.2, df.3)
```

i need a dataframe that looks like df.output

```
df.a <- c( "A", "B")
df.b <- c(300,200)
df.c <- c(2,3)
df.output <- data.frame(df.a, df.b, df.c)
```

Is there an elegant way to do this? (Can do it with subsets and merge.. but it is all but elegant)

Comment: Please explain your expected output? What do the values in columns `df.b` and `df.c`represent?

Answer (score 2):

Using `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(cbind(df.2,df.3)~df.1, df, max)
```

Output:

```
   df.a df.b df.c
1    A  300    2
2    B  200    3
```

Comment: @Cath: Thanks for correcting me as `df` is already `data.frame`.